# Proving first and third property of norm and completeness of $l_{1}$ space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a normed vector space.
$l^{1}$ and norm defined on it is
$$\lVert x\rVert = \sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right\rvert $$

I want to show the first property as follow.
$$\lVert x\rVert = 0 \iff x= 0$$
\begin{align*}
\lVert x\rVert = \sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right\rvert &= 0\\[5pt]
\iff \sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right\rvert &=0 \\[5pt]
\iff  \left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right\rvert &= 0\\[5pt]
\iff  \left \lvert x_1 + x_2 + \dotsb+ x_n \right\rvert &= 0\\[5pt]
\iff   x_1 + x_2 + \dotsb+ x_n  &= 0\\[5pt]
\iff   x  &= 0 \ \forall x_k
\end{align*}
Have I done the last step correctly?

I show the triangle Inequality like below. Is the last inequality shown is correct?
\begin{align*}
\lVert x + y \rVert = \sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n {(x_k + y_k)}\right\rvert &= \sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert {(x_1 + x_2 + \dotsb + x_n + y_1 + y_2 + \dotsb + y_n)}\right\rvert\\[5pt]
&\le \sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert {(x_1 + x_2 +\dotsb + x_n )}\right\rvert + \sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert {(y_1 + y_2 + \dotsb + y_n )}\right\rvert\\[5pt]
&\le \lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert
\end{align*}

Lastly, I want to show its completeness as below
Let $x_n $ be a Cauchy sequence in $l^1$ .
Then for $\epsilon > 0 , \exists N , \forall m,r $ such that
\begin{align*}
\lVert x^{(m)} - x^{(r)} \rVert &< \epsilon\\[5pt]
\sup_{n \geq 1} \left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n ({x_k}^{(m)} - {x_k}^{(r)} )\right\rvert &< \epsilon\\[5pt]
\left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n ({x_k}^{(m)} - {x_k}^{(r)}) \right\rvert &< \epsilon
\end{align*}

Comment: This is difficult to follow the way you've asked it - it would be much easier to address if you typed everything instead of attaching images.  The [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may help.

Comment: @DMcMor Can you check it now

Comment: I made a few more edits to line things up, but yes this is much easier to read

Comment: When you prove the first property, the last step is not correct. The reason is that I can define $x_1=1$ and $x_2=-1$ then we have $|x_1+x_2|=0$ but $x=(x_1,x_2)\neq0$. You need to use the supremum over all $n$ to get the correct answer.

Comment: @user387147 I had a doubt about this. Any hint for proving last step.

Comment: The supremum over all $n$ is zero. It means for every n, the summation is zero. Consider if $n=1$, I have $|x_1|=0$ and hence $x_1=0$. Then I consider $n=2$, then I have $|x_1+x_2|=0$. Since we have proved $x_1=0$, it means $x_2=0$. If I keep doing the same thing for all $n$, I will get $x_k=0$ for all $k$.

Comment: Mathematical induction will be helpful here, I just give you brief idea.

Comment: what about the proving Banach space part